# Custom IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole> fails when hiding the Id property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Question in relation to this, here...

[UserManager.AddToRole not working - Foreign Key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120946/usermanager-addtorole-not-working-foreign-key-error)

In my application I have a custom Role implementation

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole>
{
    public const string Admininstrator = "Administrator";

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public new Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

but when used causes this error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId". The conflict occurred
>   in database "TestDatabase", table "dbo.AspNetRoles", column 'Id'.

The culprit is this...

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public new Guid Id { get; set; }
```

removing this from the class and manually creating a unique ID works...

```
public Role()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

I would prefer the database did this for me - any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public new Guid Id { get; set; }
```

just

```
   public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole>{ }
```

and add `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` with fluent api! In custom `IdentityDbContext` class add

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     // identity
     modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Id)
         .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

When you add-migration you will see (`Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true)`)

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetRoles",
     c => new
          {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
          })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");
```